# To Set Username and Password on ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-templates

I am new at ASP.NET.I am using ASP.NET MVC Internet Application template. It contains AccountModels. I enabled migrations on AccountModels.cs. How should I edit configuration file which is created after enabling migrations in order to set username and password?

Comment: What username and password do you want to set?

Comment: I am coding basic login panel for Administrator. I want to set any username and any password. It's not important. How to set username and password is important.

Comment: Soo.. You want to create administrator accounts?

Comment: Yes. I want to create administator account. Isn't possible doing it with internet application template? If it is possible, how can I do?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7